Battery Drain on Suspend
I have installed Ubuntu 24.4.1 on a new Asus Vivobook and the the battery drains 6% per hour on suspend. When i run
cat /sys/power/mem_sleep

it outputs:
[s2idle] deep

How can I reduce the battery drain?

Well, good to know, thanks for sharing.

@mikewhatever my question is how can i reduce the battery drain?

echo 'deep' > /sys/power/mem_sleep ,
read this post When the Ubuntu laptop is turned off, the battery drains

@MMM Thank you for your comment. I think the modification that you suggested is only applied to the current session and after rebooting the value resets to [s2idle] deep. I followed the instruction in link and it reduced the 6% per hour drainage to 2%.

I also installed TLP and it reduced the 2% per hour to 1.5%.
